No inserto ni visualizo fecha Angular Net y Angular Material
Estoy realizando un CRUD de Empleados con Angular 17 (no standalone),  Angular Material y .NET 8
Todo funciona correcto. Pero estoy teniendo problemas al insertar (CREAR) un empleado. Estoy utilizando DatePicker simple de Angular Material para ingresar la fecha (ya corroboré con console.log() y me toma y envía la fecha que seleccioné) pero en la base de datos SQL Server me lo guarda como 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000 y no la fecha que seleccione en el DatePicker. Todos los otros inputs los guarda correctamente...
Además, quiero VER los datos en la lista y la fecha es la única que se visualiza vacía. Todos los demás se visualizan correctamente! El código es así:
<p><strong>Fecha:</strong> {{ empleado?.fecha | date }}</p>

Cuando quiero EDITAR el empleado trae todos los datos correctamente y aparecen en los inputs pero la fecha NO! Abajo pongo el código el input que es tanto para crear como para editar:
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Fecha de incorporación</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="fecha" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"> </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

Por último, logro editar el empleado en todos los campos, excepto en la fecha! se me guarda como les dije al principio!
En la interface de Angular el empleado.ts se ve así:
export interface Empleado {
  id?: number;
  [...]
  fecha: string;
}

En .NET hice el modelo de Empleado y junto al contexto lo migre para luego trasladarlo a SQL Server.
En el modelo la fecha está así:
public DateTime FechaInc { get; set; }

En la migración salió así:
FechaInc = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)

No logro ver el error. Ayudenme! Gracias de todo corazón

El problema es que fecha es del tipo string, cuando debería ser del tipo Date. Ahora aquí depende de varias cosas, parece que quieres tener la fecha de creación del empleado, en ese caso tienes que tomar en cuenta que SQL Server guarda la fecha en el formato local del hardware, otros gestores lo guardan en formato UTC (como PostgreSQL), cualquier cambio de hora / zona horaria tanto en backend como en frontend te puede arrojar el bug donde los datos se registren horas después o al día siguiente, tal vez en este caso te convendría dejar que la base de datos almacene la fecha al momento de que se inserte el empleado en la base de datos (usando CURRENT_TIMESTAMP por ejemplo)
Ahora para convertir la fecha en Angular tienes dos opciones:

Hacer uso de formatDate, donde podrías darle el formato que necesitas

formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en')


Usar toISOString() el cual es propio de JavaScript y retorna un string así YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ

